# What does "caller()" return in Yul when DELEGATECALL is used?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, assembly, delegatecall

While browsing the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/yul.html?highlight=caller#evm-dialect), I noticed this instruction available in assembly:

> caller(): call sender (excluding `delegatecall`)

What do the docs mean by "excluding `delegatecall`"? Is it that if contract A delegate calls to contract B, `caller()` will not return the address of contract A, but instead it would return the original EOA that called A? (I know that `msg.sender` is the same in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an empty number (0x000..0000).

You can check it yourself running the following code on Remix:

```
contract Stub {
  event Caller(uint caller);

  function testCaller() public {
      uint caller;
      assembly { caller := caller() }
      emit Caller(caller);
  }
}

contract Delegator {

  // where stub must be the address of the above contract.
  function testDelegatecall(address stub) public returns (bool) {
    (bool success,) = stub.delegatecall(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("testCaller()")
    );
    return success;
  }
}
```

Comment: The contract above doesn't compile since you are using a variable which is also the name of an instruction in assembly.
Also I believe the answer is wrong, when I tested the code on remix, it emits the EOA.